# Keras: ValueError TimeDistributed()

Tags: tensorflow, keras, time-series, classification

I am altering Keras tutorial for time series classification

```
def make_model(input_shape):
    input_layer = keras.layers.Input(input_shape)

    conv1 = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=5, padding="same")(input_layer)
    conv1 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv1)
    conv1 = keras.layers.ReLU()(conv1)
    conv1 = keras.layers.TimeDistributed(conv1)(input_layer)

    conv2 = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=5, padding="same")(conv1)
    conv2 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv2)
    conv2 = keras.layers.ReLU()(conv2)
    conv2 = keras.layers.TimeDistributed(conv2)(conv2)

    conv3 = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding="same")(conv2)
    conv3 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv3)
    conv3 = keras.layers.ReLU()(conv3)
    conv3 = keras.layers.TimeDistributed(conv3)(conv3)

    conv4 = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding="same")(conv3)
    conv4 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv4)
    conv4 = keras.layers.ReLU()(conv4)
    conv4 = keras.layers.TimeDistributed(conv4)(conv4)
    conv4 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(conv4)

    pool = keras.layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=2)(conv4)
    pool = keras.layers.TimeDistributed()(pool)

    flat = keras.layers.Flatten()(pool)
    flat = keras.layers.TimeDistributed(flat)(flat)

    lstm = keras.layers.LSTM(100)(flat)
    lstm = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(lstm)

    gap = keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')

    output_layer = keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax")(gap)

    return keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)


model = make_model(input_shape=x_train.shape[1:])
keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)
```

and get the following error:

> ValueError: Please initialize `TimeDistributed` layer with a
> `tf.keras.layers.Layer` instance. Received:
> KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 17808, 256),
> dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='re_lu_7/Relu:0',
> description="created by layer 're_lu_7'")

I have seen several codes, where people used Sequential() and add() methods. But right now, I am just struggling with this part of the code and would like to understand, how to make TimeDistributed work.

EDIT

I have an data set with shape: **(4093, 17808, 1)** - basically a one sample per row, with 4093 rows and 17808 time observations. Now I used **input_shape = (17808, 1)** before. With the code suggestions below I am kinda lost, what exactly the Reshape dimensions should be. Obviously not (32, 32, 32)

Answer (score 0):

it is importantly you need to input any shape to create a matrix that is a faster way to create time distribution. There are several points in coding you can find from your question example codes but the reason is a domain distribution to compare or scale them correctly.

Time is one channel you can relied on when you working with sequences and you do not have any domain to relate but when you working with more than one domain such as the input of inputs layers or residual networks.

Sample: Time Distribution on target domain axis.

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
num_classes = 10

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Class / Definition
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
def make_model(input_shape):
    input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(input_shape)

    conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=5, padding="same")(input_layer)
    conv1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv1)
    conv1 = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed( tf.keras.layers.ReLU() )( conv1 )

    conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=5, padding="same")(conv1)
    conv2 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv2)
    conv2 = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed( tf.keras.layers.ReLU() )( conv2 )

    conv3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding="same")(conv2)
    conv3 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv3)
    conv3 = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed( tf.keras.layers.ReLU() )( conv3 )

    conv4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding="same")(conv3)
    conv4 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv4)
    conv4 = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed( tf.keras.layers.ReLU() )( conv4 )
    conv4 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(conv4)

    pool = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((32, 32, 32))(conv4)
    pool = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed( tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=2) )( pool )

    flat = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(pool)
    flat = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((128, 128))(flat)

    lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100)(flat)
    lstm = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(lstm)

    gap = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')(lstm)

    output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax")(gap)

    return tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = make_model(input_shape=(32, 32, 3))
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)
```

Output: Print of model summary verify with target model and compare of their layers and mediums.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNgK2.png)

Comment: I have an data set with shape: (4093, 17808, 1) - basically a one sample per row, with 4093 rows and 17808 time observations.

Now I used input_shape = (17808, 1) before. With your code suggestions I am kinda lost, what exactly the Reshape dimensions should be. Obviously not (32, 32, 32)

Comment: It just dimension 4 dims to 3 dims you can try other layer, the shape does not change it does not re-order the input.